# Validation error message not showing properly

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate, charisma

I don't know how to explain it.  so just check out below image. 
[image: Jquery Validation error.]

I am using charishma Admin theme. Downloaded from here: https://github.com/usmanhalalit/charisma

I am using jquery.validate.1.11.1.js. Your any effort will be appreciated. Thanks in advance..!!
Update:

I have seen the added element is label. It seems proper for textbox and select but for checkbox and radio it shown like the abaove as the size of this elements are smaller than textbox and select. see below code is generated:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Checkboxes</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <div class="checker" id="uniform-tnc">
        <span>
          <input type="checkbox" value="option1" name="tnc" id="tnc" style="opacity: 0;" class="alert-error">
          <label for="tnc" class="alert-error">Agree to our terms and conditions to register with us.</label>
        </span>
      </div> Option 1
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is fine for all other input type except checkbox and radio. For these It should be like below :

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Checkboxes</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <div class="checker" id="uniform-tnc">
        <span>
          <input type="checkbox" value="option1" name="tnc" id="tnc" style="opacity: 0;" class="alert-error">
        </span>
      </div> Option 1
      <label for="tnc" class="alert-error">Agree to our terms and conditions to register with us.</label>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check that the markup generated is equal to the expected markup in the theme. Use web inspector or Firebug to find which rules are incorrectly applied.

Comment: Compare your markup with the expected markup, use inspection tool :)

Comment: Looks like the width of the element is set very small, so the text breaks into multiple lines. Try adding `white-space:pre` to the formatting of the element containing the error message.

Comment: @Prash278 have you tried setting a width for label? LIke 
 <label for="tnc" style="width:200px" class="alert-error">Agree to our terms and conditions to register with us.</label>

Comment: @arjucc No I am not setting any style inline. I have also checked css class it does not contains attribute of width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by adding `errorPlacement` parameter to validate. below is the solution:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  if (element.attr("name") == "tnc")
    error.appendTo($('#lbl-tnc'));
  else
    error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

And I changed the HTML as below:

```
<label class="checkbox inline" for="tnc" id="lbl-tnc">
  <input type="checkbox" name="tnc" id="tnc">I Agree to <a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any of your code for the jQuery Validate plugin in your OP.  I suggest that you create a *full* and *concise* demo of your problem, and show the demo in your OP.

By default, the jQuery Validate plugin simply inserts a `label` element immediately after the `input` element with the error.  In the case of `radio` and `checkbox` types, the `label` is inserted immediately after the *first* in the group.

Since this `label` is getting crammed, there are three ways to fix this...

1)  Edit your layout's HTML & CSS so that you have more room for the `label`.

2)  Edit the callback functions/options of the jQuery Validate plugin to place the `label` differently when the element is a `radio` or `checkbox`.

3)  Some combination of 1 & 2.